# Why logical reads are so high for a query - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration

I have a SQL query which is having way too high logical reads(769,583,044). The same query is running on a different server with less logical reads(34,693,856).The database design is same, indexing is same, CPU RAM is same, no concurrent activities in the database.Apparantly the query is scanning big tables in the database. I'm not sure how to go about the issue.

My application team is asking me why one query is running 15 mins and the other taking 45 mis to run!! please give me direction on what i need to be concentrating on.

Comment: How different is the data?  Also, show us the query plans from each.

Comment: Are the statistics up to date? There are so many possibilities here...

Comment: The data design is same.. Statistics in the bad query are up to date than the other one.Execution costs looks differnt in the both queries. So any possibility that sql is choosing the bad execution plan?

Comment: Query plans, please.

Comment: How about posting the execution plans and the query?

Comment: Not sure how to add execution plan here :( I'm Sorry!!!

Comment: Well unless you provide some details about this there is nothing anybody can do.

Comment: very big amount of reads. in your post is not enought info about it, full description should have tables structure, query, query plan, indexes. if this database is not in production you can try "alter index all on [table name] rebuild" where table name is name of each table used in query but table must have clustered index, if not then "alter table [table name] rebuild"